# How to check on CentOS 7.7 which process take 1 min because of slow page loading (TTFB 1 min)

Tags: centos, php, chrome, time-wait

I'm using CentOS version 7.7.
A few days ago my frontend page (not whole website) TTFB is exactly 1 min.
How I can check which process causes that?
I'm using PHP 7.3 php-fpm ON

Any way to check which process cause waiting for the first byte 60 seconds?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYGze.png

This error I got a few times a day ... so page availability is around 88% ... my frontpage is down (TTFB 1min) for a 12% . Please help, its very urgent for me

Comment: Page load is depend on too many factors, please check dns, ssl, system response and load including third party module for webpage if you using any.

Comment: You need to enable PHP-FPM slow log. The ridiculously slow TTFB is often a result of using external APIs, and then the remote API server is simply not responding, causing all the wait.